# How to loop in repeater dataitems after page post back

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, repeater

I have a button in repeater and I want to loop in data items of repeater in this button click event. Here is my code:

```
 protected void btnPromotionButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptPromotionProducts.Items)
             {
               if (item.DataItem == null)
                {
                    continue;
                 }...
```

And here is my repeater:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptPromotionProducts" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptPromotionProducts_OnItemDataBound">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
         <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hlProduct" CssClass="product_image">
         <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgWindow" />
           </asp:HyperLink>
              <div class="product_info">
              <h3>
               <a href="#">
                  <%# Eval("Name") %></a></h3>
                  </div>
                   <div>
                   <asp:Button ID="btnPromotionButton" runat="server" Text="Sepete Ekle" OnClick="btnPromotionButton_OnClick" />
                   </div>
                  </div>
              </li>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

item.DataItem is always comes null however repeater has rows. Is that possible to loop after page post and back?

Comment: What are you trying to get for each row? Are you trying to find out which row was clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar questions was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531531/asp-net-dataitem-of-datalist-is-null-after-postback) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888856/dataitem-on-repeater-items-is-always-null).

The short answer for this question is NO. You cannot access the DataItem after postback.

Alternatives to retrieve your data would be use a Hidden Field, a DataSource linked to your Repeater or a session object containing the data.

Comment: Although he _can_ loop through and get the values of each of those controls in his repeater (as in `item.FindControl("hlProduct")`). So I would say the long answer is YES, just do it differently. But it'd be nice to know what he is trying to accomplish.